# Unexpected closure behavior

Tags: javascript, closures

I plan to do "extension points" in a framework im building and i'm finding a way how i can provide the "core" to an extension so it can add functionality but not exposing the core object that it can be arbitrarily manipulated (i know providing an interface is the better idea) but sill, while i was testing (as well as learning), i wondered why this happens:

```
(function() {
    var core = {'bar': 'foo'}
    function getCore() {return core;}
    window.kit = {
        core: core,
        getCore: getCore
    }
}());

//initial check
console.log(kit.core)
console.log(kit.getCore());

//change the bar
kit.core.bar = 'baz';

//we will both see 'baz'
console.log(kit.core)
console.log(kit.getCore());

//null the core
kit.core = null;

//this time...
console.log(kit.core)       //core is null on this one
console.log(kit.getCore()); //why is the core still there on this one?​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between an object and an object reference.

At the beginning, `core` and `kit.core` reference the same object. Any changes to the object itself will reflect in all references to that object. However, if one of the references is changed, the other references are not automatically changed.

This line:

```
kit.core.bar = 'baz';
```

modifies the object referenced by `kit.core` and `core`. The references do not change, but the object does. This is reflected in both references.

This line:

```
kit.core = null;
```

modifies the reference `kit.core` to reference `null` but does not change `core`, which still references the original object. The object itself does not change.

Answer (score 2):

The "getCore()" function is referring to the local variable named "core", not the object property named "core".

If you changed "getCore()" to return `this.core` instead of just `core` then you'd see what you expected.

Comment: Also noted `kit.core` is not a reference or pointer. It's a value, just like the local variable `core` is a value

Comment: Raynos: `kit.core` is pointing to the `core` local object. if you modify the object the other will change as well.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If you change the **contents** of `kit.core`, then the "getCore()" function will see the change.  If, however, you just make `kit.core` refer to something new, then (as the OP discovered) the relationship is broken.